# Confusion about the meaning of "narrowly"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, confusables

What does this adverb really mean? Sometimes I even cannot understand if it has negative or positive implication. Oxford has three definition for this word:

> 1. Only just; by only a small margin. ‘the party was narrowly defeated in the elections’
> 2. Closely or carefully. he was looking at her narrowly’
> 3. In a limited or restricted way. ‘narrowly defined tasks’

My main problem is about this text:

> The man who is interested, **narrowly** interested, if you like, in
>   poetry as an art, ought never to write about bad or indifferent
>   poetry. The historian or the philosopher may.

I couldn't understand, by no means, what the writer try to convey by adding "narrowly interested, if you like".

Comment: Example number 3.

Comment: In that case I believe the author intends to say the man is interested in poetry as art and little else about it: he isn't interested in its use in polemics, say, or in social criticism, satire, or humor.

Comment: BTW, where did you get the quote? It sounds like something Wallace Stevens might have said.

Comment: @Hot Licks So could we say, or rephrase it as "The man who is interested, or to some extent interested, if you say....."?

Comment: @Robusto It is for T.S.Eliot.

Comment: No (reply to your first comment); his interest is _confined_ to poetry per se. Poetry for poetry's sake. He has a narrow focus, not being concerned about the broader and peripheral aspects.